# How to affect protected base variable in derived class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm  very new at this(object programming) and I am trying to access and then change an protected array from inherited class. But when I change it in derived class it doesn't change on in base class and that is what I want to do.

Is there a way to connect these two, like when you pass function argument by reference?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class a {
protected:
    int i=0;

public:
    void print(){
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }

}a;

class b : protected a {
public:
    void print(){
        i++;
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }

}b;

int main(){
    a.print(); //0
    b.print(); //1
    a.print(); //0  - I want this to be 1
return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `a::out()` function do?

Comment: `a` and `b` are unrelated instances.

Comment: @vahancho I guess that `out()` is actually `print()`

Comment: Have you tried making the variable static, so it is shared by all instances and derived instances?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I forgot to change it

Comment: @Eljay yes I did but I don't quite understand how static works

Comment: A static variable is associated with the class, not with a particular instance of the class.  So all instances of the class will be accessing/mutating the same single class variable.  You might want to pick up a good C++ book: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is effectively doing

```
Ford myFord;                     // a a;
BlueFord yourFord;               // b b;

myFord.printMileage();           // a.print();
yourFord.driveAndPrintMileage(); // b.print(); <- does more than printing!
myFord.printMileage();           // a.print();
```

There is no reason why `myFord`'s mileage should change when `yourFord` is being driven. They are the same **kind** of car (a `Ford`, with the latter being the special blue edition), but they are not **the same** car (one is yours, one is mine). Driving one doesn't change the mileage of the other.

You use the same name for the **type** (`Ford`) and the instance (`myFord`) of each class/variable. Those are fundamentally different things and giving them the same name doesn't make them one and the same thing (it just makes things more confusing for you).

Making `i` a `static` variable would "sync" it between all the instances - it's as if each `Ford` car was always connected to the internet and broadcasted changes to `i` to all other `Ford`s. Imagine `static int i` as a "total miles driven by all (blue) fords ever" counter. But note that a `static` variable no longer lives in one of the instances (it's not stored in each `Ford`) but somewhere centrally (some Ford company server).

But the entire idea of object oriented programming is getting rid of global state (which includes `static` variables) and have each **instance** manage its own state. I don't want my `Ford` to talk to all other `Ford`s constantly, relying on some external connection.

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` are unrelated objects, each with their own copy of the `i` member variable. `a.i` and `b.i` are different variables, and so changing one does not affect the other.

Also, your class names are poorly chosen. You have an `a` class and an `a` object. That's just confusing. Capitalize the first letter of class names instead. Name them `A` and `B`.

It seems that what you want to do here is call the two different `print()` functions *on the same object*. You can do:

```
B b_obj;           // Create an object of type B
b_obj.A::print();  // Calls A::print() on b_obj
b_obj.print();     // Calls B::print() on b_obj
b_obj.A::print();  // Calls A::print() on b_obj
```

Note though that there's an issue with the `print()` function. Both `A` and `B` have one, and this will result in some surprising behavior when dealing with polymorphism. However, I assume you've not reached that part yet. For now, just keep in mind that having a member function in a derived class that has the same name as a function in a base class can be very problematic, unless the base function is marked as `virtual`. But I guess you'll come to that part of the book (or whatever you're using to learn C++) soon enough.